# I thought Python passed everything by reference?

Tags: python, scope

Take the following code

```
#module functions.py
def foo(input, new_val):
    input = new_val

#module main.py
input = 5
functions.foo(input, 10)

print input
```

I thought input would now be 10.  Why is this not the case?

Comment: You may be confusing yourself by calling the local variable "input" in the definition of function foo. Also, what Sven said in the answers.

Comment: Wherever you've read that Python passes everything by reference, they were wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything is passed by value, but that value is a reference to the original object.  If you modify the object, the changes are visible for the caller, but you can't reassign names.  Moreover, many objects are immutable (ints, floats, strings, tuples).

Comment: "[Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)" illustrates this phenomenon well.

Comment: Python isn't call-by-value or call-by-reference, see my answer for details.

Comment: @skyhisi: Your answer is essentially the same as mine, except for using the non-standard term "call by object", which I intentionally avoided because it does not explain anythin.

Answer (score 8):

Inside foo, you're binding the local name `input` to a different object (`10`). In the calling context, the name `input` still refers to the `5` object.

Answer (score 5):

Assignment in Python does not modify an object in-place. It rebinds a name so that after `input = new_val`, the local variable `input` gets a new value.

If you want to modify the "outside" `input`, you'll have to wrap it inside a mutable object such as a one-element list:

```
def foo(input, new_val):
    input[0] = new_val

foo([input])
```

Python does not do pass-by-reference exactly the way C++ reference passing works. In this case at least, it's more as if every argument is a pointer in C/C++:

```
// effectively a no-op!
void foo(object *input, object *new_val)
{
    input = new_val;
}
```

Comment: thanks for everyone's answers... this method you suggested seems almost like a hack, is this standard procedure? are there any other ways to modify immutable types that is more pythonic? (i guess 'modify immutable types' answers my own question but i'll ask anyway...)

Comment: @Ferguzz You can't modify immutable objects by definition. But is that really what you meant to ask? So far, immutable objects haven't even been mentioned. The fact that `var = ...` doesn't modify any object or any other variable has nothing to do with immutability. You simply can't make one variable assignment change another variable just like you can't make changes to one list affect another list.

Comment: i was referring to the line in this answer 'wrap it inside a mutable object such as a list'.  I was trying to ask, is there a way to modify the variable as in my original post, without doing this?

Comment: @Ferguzz: this is very much a hack. Usually, you wouldn't do this at all, you'd just return the new value from the function and assign `new_val = foo()`; that's the pythonic solution.

Answer (score 4):

Python is neither call-by-value, or call-by-reference, it is [Call By Object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm).

> "Arguments are passed by call-by-sharing, *similar* to
>       call-by-value, *except* that the arguments are objects
>       and can be changed only if they are mutable."

Comment: Nice summary, but still I believe that call-by-object is no different than call-by-value, with all "values" being handles (~= pointers) to objects.

Comment: @Kos that's simply confusing implementation details with the semantics of the evaluation strategy. You could, for example, implement Python entirely in Fortran using only call by reference in the fortran implementation, but that wouldn't make *Python's* semantics "call by reference"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wow, hello from 2020. Can't really comment on Fortran but I still think we're ultimately looking at a problem with confusing naming - "Call by object" may or may not imply "call by value" depending on your favourite definition. "Call by object" = "call by value where the reference itself is considered a variable's value" or something...

Answer (score 0):

Well, python functions are neither call-by-reference nor  call-by-value, they are call-by-object.
before applying this concept on functions, let's take a look at those code snippets:

1-

```
listA = [0]
listB = listA
listB.append(1)
print (listA) # [0, 1]
```

2-

```
listA = [0]
listB = listA
listB = [2, 3]
print(listA) # [0]
```

In the first code snippet, listB was able to access the objects stored in listA and modify them BUT IT COULDN'T MODIFY listA in the second code snippet, as they are not the same thing! you passed a container of objects and were able to modify the objects in that container but, you can't modify that container itself.
in your code:

```
def foo(input, new_val):
    input = new_val
input = 5
foo(input, 10)
print (input)
```

you can't modify the variable 'input' because you don't have it!
Passing by object is a very confusing concept and reminds me with Quantum Physics but, try playing around with the code and you will understand it well.
you can check the following links for more illustrations:

[geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/)

[ROBERT HEATON blog](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/#:%7E:text=Python%20is%20different.,as%20used%20by%20the%20caller.)